# google maps markers and mouse movement

Tags: google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3, mouse

I have a map loaded and a listener:

```
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapdiv'),opts);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map,'mousemove',function(event) {...
```

All fine. And I also have a mouse click event being captured to relay coordinates to a database.

But I've added waypoints to the map

```
for (var wp in waypoints) {
    var wpOptions = {strokeColor: waypoints[wp].clr,strokeOpacity: 0.5,strokeWeight: 2,fillColor: waypoints[wp].clr,
    fillOpacity: 0.1,map: map,center: waypoints[wp].center,radius:waypoints[wp].sz
    };
    wpCircle = new google.maps.Circle(wpOptions);
```

But some of the circles (wpCircle) can cover quite a large area - this stops the mouse move and click events. Is there any way to make the circles invisible to the mouse movement so the mouse responds to the underlying map and ignores the objects that have been laid on?

Many thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Whoops happened again. Found the answer and was looking too deeply.

clickable:false

```
for (var wp in waypoints) {
    var wpOptions = {strokeColor: waypoints[wp].clr,strokeOpacity: 0.5,strokeWeight: 2,fillColor: waypoints[wp].clr,
    fillOpacity: 0.1,map: map,center: waypoints[wp].center,radius:waypoints[wp].sz,clickable: false 
    };
```

This is perfect now.
Thanks anyway

Kevin